# Как сделать ленивую выборку в регулярке?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст

```
<name>Иванов</name><family>Сергей</family><otch>Петрович</otch><age>37</age><name>Васечкин</name><family>Юрий</family><otch>Антонович</otch><age>16</age><name>Яковлев</name><family>Павел</family><otch>Александрович</otch><age>25</age><total>115</total>
```

Как выделить этот промежуток:
http://joxi.ru/gkrDpqjNH9erpX.png?d=

Пытался сделать этой регуляркой

```
((?<=<name).+?(?<=</total>))
```

Выделяет весь текст почему-то.

Comment: echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '<name>')-1);

Answer (score 1):

```
(<name>[А-Яа-я]+</name>(<family>[А-Яа-я]+</family>)?(<otch>[А-Яа-я]+</otch>)?(<age>\d+</age>)?<total>\d+</total>)
```

Так пойдет?

```
(<name>[А-Яа-я]+</name>(<family>[А-Яа-я]+</family>)?(<otch>[А-Яа-я]+</otch>)?(<age>\d+</age>)?(?=<total>))
```

Или так, если последний тег не нужен.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы только копировал выборку, в которой нет тега total?

Comment: Добавил строчкой ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Ну... понятно, почему весь:

**ИвановСергейПетрович37ВасечкинЮрийАнтонович16ЯковлевПавелАлександрович25115****

Вместо .+? используйте конструкцию, запрещающую вхождение  повторно.

А еще лучше использовать [xml парсер](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document).

Comment: А что за конструкция, если не секрет? )

Comment: Извините, почитал сейчас статьи, похоже, нету такого. Жаль. @_Александр_ ниже хорошо написал. Но я еще раз рекомендую распарсить xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: Всё есть: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481255/178988

Answer (score 0):

```
/<name>((?!<name>).)+<\/total>/
```